# How to add cartoon face on Camera Preview using Android

Tags: android, sdk, android-camera, face-detection, glsurfaceview

I have a Module to put cartoon face on eyes or anywhere else on live Camera Preview. I am using Moodme Sdk. I have implemented camera preview. I m getting landmark x and y axis value. But I don't know where do i add those landmark and how to put that image on eyes using landmark. This is code for while getting person face on live camera.

```
 @Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
    if (image == null) {
        return;
    }
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] yBytes = new byte[yBuffer.remaining()];
    yBuffer.get(yBytes);
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    byte[] uBytes = new byte[uBuffer.remaining()];
    uBuffer.get(uBytes);
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
    byte[] vBytes = new byte[vBuffer.remaining()];
    vBuffer.get(vBytes);

    tracker.processImageBuffer(yBytes, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH, MDMTrackerManager.FrameFormat.GRAY);
    //renderer.updateTextureImage(yBytes, uBytes, vBytes, image.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride());
    image.close();

    if (tracker.isFaceTracked()) {
    //    renderer.updateVertices();
    }

    if (tracker.isFaceTracked()) {
        // translate to opengl coordinates
        float[] landmarks = new float[66*2];


        for (int i = 0; i < 66; ++i) {
            if(i >=17 && i <27 || i >=36 && i <48 ) {
                landmarks[2 * i] = 1.0f - tracker.getLandmarks()[2 * i] / (HEIGHT / 2);
                landmarks[2 * i + 1] = 1.0f - tracker.getLandmarks()[2 * i + 1] / (WIDTH / 2);
            }
        }
      // renderer.updateLandmarks(landmarks);
    } else {
      //  renderer.updateLandmarks(null);
    }

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double fps = 1000.0 / (currentTime - lastFrameTime);

    updater.update(fps);

    lastFrameTime = currentTime;
}
```

I have also used Face Detection Library But that is not giving me accurate result.Is There any good Library For Face detection and put image or Mask on Camera Preview. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are many libraries available which add a face mask on camera preview. Almost all of them use OpenCV. Check out these libraries.

- [FaceFilter](https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/FaceFilter)
- [Face Replace](https://github.com/marsbroshok/face-replace)
- [FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker)
- [Android GPUimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)

The [Android GPUimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) seems to add image on Camera Preview. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154572/save-applied-filter-in-camera-preview-with-gpuimage) used this library to add face mask on camera preview. You can take a look into the answer posted on the question.

The FaceFilter library does the same work, but on a captured image. However you can see the [tutorial](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/android-mobile-vision-api-face-filter-implementation/) for the library posted by the author and integrate it with face detection. There are several tutorials for face detection. This [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-face-detection-on-android--cms-25212) explains how to implement face detection, while also overlaying graphics on it. Although there is not much on the overlaid graphics in the tutorial, it might solve your question.

Comment: sir i have used above some library. but that is for image on image.and I want live camera preview on that other .png image.And i need library for android only not for ios.

Comment: sir actually i don't want only face detection. I want eye and ear x and y axis though i m getting eye exact position but i m not able to find ear x and y axis.so that i can put image on eye. Above link i already tried.

Comment: The tutorial explains about additional face data too at the end. Use that to your advantage.